# Stability of non-linear systems with linear feedback

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

I am using a standard steps for designing a controller for a non-linear system i.e. linearization about equilibrium point, checking closed loop stability of the linear system with a linear controller. Is it possible to prove theoretically the stability of the same controller on the non-linear system for given operating range?

Comment: This is too broad a question to give an answer. Sometimes you can (obviously it works for linear systems :-)), sometimes it is difficult.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you point me to the relevant literature ? or keywords would also be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I am not current, but you could look at Lyapunov theory, backstepping, feedback linearisation. Its a big topic. When you go non linear things become much more specialised.

Comment: Get the Lyapunov function of the linearized system. Then using this Lyapunov function for the original system you could find a region of convergence. If you don't care about global convergence this will tell you a region of initial conditions that the control works for. If you need to prove global convergence then start looking for a Lyapunov function.

Comment: I would guess (don't place much in this) that Lyapunov, linearisation, sliding mode would be good starting points. By linearisation I mean using feedback to 'linearise' as system, not just linearising the system dynamics.

Comment: Recent new theory on Incremental Dissipativity or Incremental Stability might be interesting for you!